# Magento 2 {{ directives }} reference

Tags: magento2

Does someone can point me to the official reference documentation for url directives such as

`{{store url....}}`

`{{view ....}}`

etc?
Thanks

Comment: which URL you want to get in static or cms page? like store url, theme images url or media URL?

Answer (score 1):

docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/markup-tags.html
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/markup-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Official Documentation but you can get your answer from this Link

Please [Click Here](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/directives/)

Comment: thank you, i've already read that article

Comment: This is only solution.